# Map undefined when using return

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have encountered an issue that I can't immediatly explain and would like to. If I write the following code

```
this.metadata = json.metadata.map((x) => {return new Metadatum(x);});
console.log(this.metadata[0].value);
```

the output is 'undefined' for every element in json.metadata.

If, I write the following (bad use of the map function, I know I could just write a forEach here and the results are the same)

```
json.metadata.map(x => this.metadata.push(new Metadatum(x)));
console.log(this.metadata[0].value);
```

Now I get the correct results, not undefined.

Why is it that the assignment to this.metadata (which is a Metadatum[]) has undefined?

Comment: Could it be that `this.metadata` already has valid values before, and your second way doesn't work either but you don't see it because you are not clearing the previous elements before pushing new ones?

Comment: @CherryDT this.metadata essentially was just declared as an array above that. (metadata : Metadatum[])

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the below options to use `.map`:

```
var data = [1, 2,3,4,5,6,7];
function Metadatum (x) {
  this.value = x;
}

let metadata = data.map((x) => { return new Metadatum(x); });
let metadata1 = data.map(x => new Metadatum(x));
console.log(metadata[0].value);
console.log(metadata1[0].value);
```

Some of the syntax for ES6 lambda is as below:

```
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => { statements }
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression
     // equivalent to:  => { return expression; }

// Parentheses are optional when there's only one parameter:
(singleParam) => { statements }
```

singleParam => { statements }

```
// A function with no parameters requires parentheses:
() => { statements }
```

For a detailed syntax of arrow functions refer this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

EDIT: Here is a JSBin link with working example: https://jsbin.com/huzuyo/1/edit?html,js,console

Comment: I am aware of this, yet the value is undefined when I use that syntax. I can just push it directly to the array and it is not undefined

Comment: Can you create a JSBin, codepen or plunkr to show this ? I have edited my answer and added a JSBin link

Answer (score 0):

you should check your data structure; `.map` get an array and then returns a new one.
checkout this example:

```
var kvArray = [
    {key:1, value:10},
    {key:2, value:20}, 
    {key:3, value: 30}
];

var reformattedArray = kvArray.map(function(obj){ 
    var rObj = {};
    rObj[obj.key] = obj.value;
    return rObj;
});
```